# How to include windows header files in C++/WinRT App?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++-winrt

I am working in a C++/WinRT project type. I need to use members from winuser.h. MSDN says to include windows.h which automatically includes winuser.h. When I do this the include statement for windows.h reports no errors. However, when I try to access members of windows.h or winuser.h in my code the compiler reports "identifier undefined". I find it strange that I would need to set a normal Win32 header file as an external dependency. Shouldn't Visual Studio be able to find these files all by itself? Does anyone know what's happening here? Am I referencing the members wrong in my code? I was under the belief that once a header file is included I could reference its members directly.

Comment: Well you also need to link the Win32 libraries (e.g. user32.lib), just including the headers won't be enough. I'm not sure that it will fix your problem though. But that's a must step.

Comment: Are you targeting the UWP? In case you are, are the functions you are trying to call available for UWP applications?

Comment: Has your problem been resolved? It your problem is not resolved, please feel free and contact us.

Comment: Shouldn't this fall under the windowsapp.lib include? I am trying to do the same and MSDN says Visual Studio 2022 will automatically include windowsapp.lib in new C++/WinRT project types, but still I get "identifier "WNDCLASS" is undefined". Am I missing an include or namespace directive? I have checked Project Properties and the windowsapp.lib is included.